# How to display processes in listview WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to display all processes, namely: Process name, ID, and priority in ListView

I tried:

```
public Process[] processes;
public string[] processesss;
public MainWindow() {
   InitializeComponent();
   processes = Process.GetProcesses();
   ProcessInfo.ItemsSource = processes;
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="ProcessInfo">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Process Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{ProcessName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Process ID" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{ID}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="70"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Please note that your question is too broad. Consider asking a question describing a particular and isolated issue. It is well explained in our [ask] topics.

Comment: You might want to search for and look into some guides/tutorials about [DataTemplates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) in WPF...

Comment: This code will run and bind to something like a DataGrid with your current code. However the you will need to create columns for your ListView. You are missing `ProcessInfo.DisplayMemberPath = "ProcessName"`

Comment: It's Id not ID and `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProcessName}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
            InitializeComponent();
            processes = Process.GetProcesses();
            List<processlist> processlist = new List<processlist>();
            foreach (Process item in processes)
             {
              processlist.Add(new processlist() { id = item.Id, name = item.ProcessName });
             }
            ProcessInfo.ItemsSource = processlist;
```

and add this class

```
 public class processlist
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

WPF UI

```
<Grid >
        <ListView Margin="10" Name="ProcessInfo">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="id" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}" />
                  </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Just make sure your UI element has got correct binding information to pick properties from the `ItemsSource`. Could be a bit easier for you if you replace `ListView` with a `DataGrid` and set its `AutoGenerateColumns` to `True`. This will automatically start showing your processes in the grid.

On the other hand, you can use `ListView` or even `ListBox` for your purpose, but then you'll have to set up `ItemTemplate` for your control, which is a broad topic in itself.